# Explain this mysql query please?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT salary FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT n-1,1
```

This query is to find nth highest salary. If possible explain with the example?

Comment: look up LIMIT in the documentation.

Comment: Where did you found this query, have you even tried to learn sql by yourself ? What are you trying to do. This is not a real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  `# Retrieve rows 6-15`
```

`5` - startIndex

`10` - No of records from start index

[`see here`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT salary` - To select only salary column
`FROM employee` - Do the above operation on employee table
`ORDER BY salary DESC` - Sort the result by salary in decreasing order
`LIMIT n-1,1` - Show the result starting from (n-1)<sup>th</sup> index and show only 1 row.

*NOTE - index start from 0 that's why `(n-1)` is used instead of `n.`*